# Does the amount of pages from one process depend on memory size

Tags: memory

I read somewhere that only the pages that a process needs to start up are loaded in memory, then as the program runs more pages may be loaded into memory depending on the code or data you're trying to use.

Does this always happen or does it depend on how much memory you have and what is loaded already? For example, if you have only started one process and have a lot of memory, are all the pages that can fit in memory loaded, or are they loaded depending on what you do?

Comment: programs allocated dynamic memory at runtime as needed, and when an allocation fails due to insufficient memory, an error is thrown. the OS attempts to prevent this from happening a number of ways, but the ultimate result is the same. a program could be written to use more or less memory based on the amount provisioned, but it is very unlikely. No the OS does not preallocate pages just because it thinks a program might use them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it always happens. It doesn't at all depend on how much RAM you have.

What DOES happen is that with more RAM on the system (and everything else being equal), processes will be allowed to keep more of those pages, rather than enduring "working set replacement." Working set replacement happens when the process wants to fault in a page but the system, due to limited free RAM, is enforcing process working set limits. At such times  the process will have to release a page from its working set for every page it brings in.

So when you look at the processes on a large memory system you'll find they are generally all sitting on more RAM (larger working sets) than on a system with significantly less memory. But it isn't because of any pre-loading. It's because of lack of loss of pages later.